how to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^{m+n}}{m-n}$?
I tried to find the summation
$$ \Omega=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1 , m\ne n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m+n} H_{m+n}}{m^2-n^2}$$
and got
$$ \Omega=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t} \left( \frac{t^2}{1-t^2} \ln(1+t)-f(t) \right) dt$$
where
$$ f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^{m+n}}{m-n} $$
now to find $f(t)$ we have
$$ f(t)=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} (-t)^{m+n} x^{m-n-1} dx=\int_0^1 x^{-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{-t}{x} \right)^n \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} (-tx)^{m}dx$$
So
$$ f(t)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x(1+tx)} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(tx \left(\frac{-t}{x} \right)^n+t^{2n-1} \right) dx$$
now is it correct to evaluate that series ? where we have $0<t<1 , 0<x<1 $
I think I made wrong So how can I find $f(t)$ ?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^{m+n}}{m-n}
= 
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^{m+n}}{n-m}
$$
$$
= 
-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{(-t)^{m+n}}{n-m}
$$
Substituting $d=n-m$ gives a geometric series
$$
= 
-\sum_{d=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^{m+d+m}}{d}
= 
-\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^d}{d} \sum_{m=1}^\infty (-t)^{2m}
$$
$$
= 
-\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^d}{d} (-)\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}
= 
\frac{t^2}{t^2-1}\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{(-t)^d}{d}
= 
-\frac{t^2}{t^2-1} \log(1+t)
$$

that's great so the harmonic series I put will be zero ? thanks for the solution

The harmonic series is zero because for each $(m,n)$ with denominator $m^2-n^2$ there is a swapped $(n,m)$ with denominator $n^2-m^2$ which obviously cancel.
